# Using DBUA for oracle on two different servers

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

newbie to the oracle database world...

I have a database on 11g and I want to migrate this over to 12C and then from the 12C upgrade that particular database...

Any particular help / how-to's on how to do this?

I did testing with SQL Developer and migrated one table from 11G to 12C with no issues.

Any suggestions on how to get the database copied over.

Answer (score 0):

there are thousands of docs and howto's about this topic.
So all depands on your enviroment ( Data, DB, Location of Files, Target OS, Source OS..... and so on.)
"with no issus" is the main goal of every dba and need a lot of practise and knowing about the oracle architecture.

- copying db files (data, control, redo, pfile/spfile, password file.....) to the new location -> maybe you have to relocate these in the controlfiles
  .. and so on....

So nobody can told you here a step-by-step guide for your task.

It can be easy if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the input... How do you get the new server to recognize the database?

Comment: this depands on your os! If you on windows you have to create a service for you instanz. on linux there is no need for the server to recognize a db! if there is the correct oracle software installed and all your files are present and at the correct location you can start and work with you database. For DBUA there is the "oratab" file interessting. Maybe you have to put in the moved db.